# Firestore batch completes even when arrayRemove() operation in the batch fails to succeed

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, batch-processing

I'm attempting to update a nested object within a Firestore array. This requires that the original object is removed from the array using `arrayRemove()` and the updated object is added using `arrayUnion()`. These two operations are made within a batch to ensure they both occur, with the expectation that the batch will fail if either of the operations fails. Here is some sample code using Swift:

```
let batch = db.batch()
         
let docRef = db.collection("events").document("20220715")
let encodedRemove = try! Firestore.Encoder().encode(originalEvent)
let encodedUpdate = try! Firestore.Encoder().encode(updatedEvent)

batch.updateData(["dayEvent": FieldValue.arrayRemove([encodedRemove])], forDocument: docRef)
batch.updateData(["dayEvent": FieldValue.arrayUnion([encodedUpdate])], forDocument: docRef)

batch.commit() { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing batch \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Batch write succeeded.")
    }
}
```

This works as expected when making an update. The value of the original object is stored locally to pass to `arrayRemove()` and a new object is created for the update to pass to `arrayUnion()`. The batch is then passed to Firestore which removes the original object and adds the updated object.

However, if the original object is modified on then server after it has been stored locally, the batch still succeeds without removing the original object using `arrayRemove()`.  Since the object has changed on the server, I'd expect the `arrayRemove()` call to fail since there is no longer a match for the object to remove from the array. However, `arrayRemove()` seems to silently fail in the batch--the array object is not removed, but the updated object is added to the array.  In turn, this leave 2 objects in different states within the array.

Why is the batch operation still completing even though `arrayRemove()` operation has failed?  As highlighted in the docs, in a batch operation, "either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied."

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: There's a typo in the question `encodedRemoval` and the var being used is `([encodedRemove])]`

Comment: Thanks for catching the type--I've updated the sample code above, but the core itself still remains.

Comment: Does `.arrayRemove` actually *fail* is the value to remove isn't found? I have not tested it one way or the other. When I have a chance I will test unless you know that answer.

Comment: `arrayRemove` needs to have a perfect match of the object for the array element to be removed.  If the match is not perfect (e.g. if the object on the server is now different from what was passed via `arrayRemove`), `arrayRemove` will fail to remove the object--but there is no indication that `arrayRemove` has failed and the batch operation continues on.

Comment: The issue is that `.arrayRemove` is not a failable call to begin with, therefore it will never fail nor throw an error. That means neither a batch nor a transaction will fail if the value to be removed is not found.

Comment: That make sense.  I guess I had assumed that since `batch.updateData` or `transaction.updateData` are both bailable that the `arrayRemove` call within it would be. Alas.  Thanks for looking into it.